# IPSec tunnel between FortiGate and iPhone / iOS - Works except for DNS / Wins

Tags: vpn, ipsec, internal-dns, iphone, fortinet

I have configured my Fortigate with a new VPN IPSec tunnel to allow the iOS Cisco client to connect.  That works fine.  I can RDP to my servers, browse to my servers via IP address, etc.

But, the iPhone does not resolve my internal IP addresses.  I have added the DNS servers that serve addresses for my internal users, as well as the WINS servers, but the iPhone acts like it doesn't see them at all.

```
config vpn ipsec phase1-interface
    edit "iPhone_VPN"
        set type dynamic
        set interface "wan1"
        set dhgrp 2
        set proposal 3des-sha1 3des-md5
        set xauthtype auto
        set mode-cfg enable
        set authusrgrp "iPhone_VPN_Users"
        set ipv4-start-ip 10.10.99.100
        set ipv4-end-ip 10.10.99.199
        set ipv4-netmask 255.255.0.0
        set ipv4-dns-server1 10.10.2.1
        set ipv4-dns-server2 10.22.1.80
        set ipv4-wins-server1 10.10.2.1
        set ipv4-wins-server2 10.22.1.80
        set ipv4-split-include "Dialup_VPN_Networks"
        set psksecret ENC xxxxx
    next
end
```

For whatever reason, as far as I can tell, the iPhone does not 'see' the DNS or WINS entries.  I don't know how to check it...

Comment: Have you flushed the DNS cache of the iPhone? anyway I don't know that much iOS but you can try to check if there is some command similiar to:
HOST
DIG
in the Unix world

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you need to configure some firewall policies.
Source interface should be iPhone_VPN and destination interface is the interface where your DNS and WINS server are connected to.
Hope it helps.
-Pietro.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable split tunelling for the DNS requests to be internal and not external!

UNSET `ipv4-split-include "Dialup_VPN_Networks"` will do the trick.